# PHP DateTime::format() returns wrong date in 1995

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I've got a timestamp like 812671200. https://timestampconvert.net/ says it is 10/03/1995 00:00:00. Fine.

But if I want to format it in PHP like this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(812671200);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin')); // my timezone
echo $date->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
```

It says: 10/02/1995 23:00:00
Using "UTC" as timezone returns: 10/02/1995 22:00:00

I read on Wikipedia, that in 1996 DST changed to last Sunday in October, so I tried different timestamps like last Saturday, Sunday of September 1995, they formatted fine, but Monday after last Sunday of September 1995 did not format right.

> ### [Wikipedia - Daylight saving time by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country)
>
> 1981–1995 last Sunday of March to last Sunday of September.
> Since 1996 last Sunday of March to last Sunday of October.

Is this a problem with PHP or am I doing something wrong?
Help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Set the timezone first, setting it afterwards converts time from whatever the default TZ was.

Comment: At October 1995, [Berlin wasn't in DST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin?year=1990). At that year, DST started in March 26th and ended in September 24th. So, in October it wasn't in DST and the offset was +01:00 (one hour ahead UTC). So the value is correct: 812671200 is `1995-10-02T22:00 UTC` and `1995-10-02T23:00+01:00 (Berlin)`: https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=812671200&tz=Europe%2FBerlin